# Complex analysis: relationship between a complex number and its reciprocal number

Tags: complex-numbers

The question is:
Let $z_1...z_n$ be non-zero complex numbers such that 
$$\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{z_i}=0$$ 
Prove for any line passing through the origin, the number $z_1...z_n$ cannot all lie in a half-plane on either side of the line.

To solve this, I tried using the argument of $z$ and $\frac1z$, but I have not got anything particularly useful. I also thought using vector notation of complex number in a 2d plane could help, but can't find a way to formalize that. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/185523/a-finite-sum-of-reciprocals-of-complex-numbers-cannot-be-confined-to-a-half-plan?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer that positrón0802 linked to is really clean, but here's another possible approach.

---

First, note that this is easily true when the line is the imaginary axis.

Then for an arbitrary line, with inclination $\theta$ away from the imaginary axis, let $w_i = z_i e^{-i \theta}$. Essentially, you're rotating the plane so that the line becomes the imaginary axis. Also,
$$ \sum_i \frac{1}{w_i} = \sum_i \frac{1}{z_i e^{-i \theta}} = e^{i \theta} \sum_i \frac{1}{z_i} = 0 $$

So we've reduced to the first case.

Answer (score 0):

Let $r$ be a line passing through the origin. Then, for some $\omega$ with $|\omega|=1$, $r=\{\lambda\omega\,|\,\lambda\in\mathbb{R}\}$. Now, suppose that $z_1,\ldots,z_n$ are all in one side of $r$. Then each $z_j$ can be written as $w_j\omega$, with $\operatorname{Im}w_j>0$ (if they are all smaller than $0$, the argument is the same). But then$$0=\sum_{j=1}^n\frac1{z_j}=\sum_{j=1}^n\frac1{w_j\omega}=\frac1\omega\sum_{j=1}^n\frac1{w_j}.$$However, this last sum cannot be $0$, since the imaginary part of each $\frac1{w_j}$ is smaller than $0$:

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(z)=\prod\limits_{k=1}^n(z-z_k)$.

Hence, our condition gives $f'(0)=0$.